# Windows Reader from taking full screen whenever I click pdf file in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, pdf, fullscreen

I have a Windows 8.1 on my DELL.  Whenever I 
How do we Stop Windows Reader from taking full screen whenever I click pdf file in Windows 8.1?  I just want to make Windows Reader smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the Metro reader app. If you open with regular "Adobe Reader" not MS's "Reader" then you wont have a problem.